# Ejecting non-storage USB devices on Mac

Tags: macos, usb, virtualbox

I have a Mac running VirtualBox with a Win 8.1 client VM.

I have a program to run in the VM that requires access to a USB dongle — note, ***not* a storage device**! Sadly, whenever the Mac restarts it grabs the dongle, so before the VM can use it remote hands must physically remove it from the Mac and plug it in again.

Is there some way to programmatically eject (virtually, not physically of course) such a USB device from the Mac so that the VM can then take over ownership? I'll be happy to dig into I/O Kit or whatever Framework in Cocoa may be needed to accomplish this. I'd just rather not start if it's obviously impossible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24318375/733626) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24335748/733626) is similar to what I'm looking for, but Step 6 is "Remove the USB device from your physical machine." I'm trying to avoid fiddling with the physical hardware by hand so that I can automate the process.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this question on Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48854/ejecting-usb-drive-via-applescript-does-not-make-drive-power-down (I am not sure if it counts as a real duplication if it's on a different SE site.) Either way, I hope the answer there helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but nope. That's specifically about ejecting storage. This dongle is not storage.